# Reduce the redundancy in my pandas highlight function

Tags: python, pandas

After a lot of browsing and experimenting I have managed to achieve to read excel file as a Dataframe, apply some style to it and export it to html. My main concern is that the highlight_max function looks a bit redundant. The rows I want to highlight are already predetermined and are not just simply minimum or maximum. I tried to do it with list comprehension but it did not work. Is it possible to return the style value with just one line?

```
import pandas as pd

def highlight_max(s):    
    truth = []
    for i in (df.index):
        truth.append(i in [634, 636, 638, 640, 642, 644, 648, 649, 650, 651, 656])
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in truth]

df = pd.read_excel('N:\Temp\filename.xlsx', index_col=False) 
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
html = df.style.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th,td', 'props': [('border-style','solid'),
('border-width','1px')]}]).apply(highlight_max).hide_index().render(index=False)
with open('N://temp//test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `highlight_max` function can be simplified a bit by passing the rows to mark as an argument (possibly with a default value), and putting it all into a list comprehension right away:

```
def highlight_max(column, to_mark):    
    return ['background-color: yellow' if i in to_mark else '' for i in column.index]
```

Note that this takes the actual `column` as input. Yours took the `df` from the global scope, disregarding the input, which means that all things you did before the `apply` will probably be ignored.

Use it like this:

```
ROWS = {634, 636, 638, 640, 642, 644, 648, 649, 650, 651, 656}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_excel('N:\Temp\filename.xlsx', index_col=False) 
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    styles = [{'selector': 'th,td',
               'props': [('border-style','solid'), ('border-width','1px')]}]
    html = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)\
             .apply(highlight_max, to_mark=ROWS)\
             .hide_index()\
             .render(index=False)

    with open('N://temp//test.html', 'w') as f:
        f.write(html)
```

I also made `ROWS` a `set` instead of a `list` for faster checking of `in` (not that it matters too much for such a small list, but it will if it gets bigger), used a style that makes the long chain of functions for `html` easier to read IMO, used the fact that any additional parameters passed to `apply` are passed along to the function to pass the rows to mark and wrapped the main code under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script without it running.